# How to use jagged array in fixed statement?

Tags: c#

Is there a way to access/set values in jagged array like this?

```
Block[][][] blocks;
void SetBlock(int x, int y, int z, Block block)
{
   fixed (Block*** b = blocks)
   {
      b[z][y][x] = block;
   }
}
Block GetBlock(int x, int y, int z)
{
   fixed (Block*** b = blocks)
   {
       return b[z][y][x];
   }
}
```

Comment: I believe you will have to fix the array at each level

Comment: @RomanWieszkowski fixed should have no performance impact. If anything, it should slighly improove performance at that is one thing the GC should not even look at (anymore). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/fixed-statement

Comment: I'm calling these methods from huge nested loops and the array itself is huge so i thought that the index checking can slow it down (or add additional instructions). Even 5 ms improvement is alot to me or less cpu time.

Comment: @RomanWieszkowski Indexing is not a huge deal. The JiT is pretty good at indexer check pruning, however I asume it can not work into fixed areas. But it is just about as likely that the checks themself are supressed in unsafe code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible. According to [the C# language specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/unsafe-code#the-fixed-statement):

> A fixed_pointer_initializer can be one of the following:
>   
> …
>
> - An expression of an array_type with elements of an unmanaged type T

A jagged array involves arrays of arrays (or in your case, arrays of arrays of arrays). Each array object is a *managed* type, and so an array of an array can't be used in `fixed`.

Note that this also means that depending on what `Block` is, you might not even be able to use `fixed` with a single-dimensional array of type `Block`. If it's a class, `Block` is an actual managed type, so an array of `Block` also isn't allowed. Only if it's a struct containing only other unmanaged types would it be permitted.

All that said, if you did have a jagged array of *unmanaged* types (e.g. `int`, `double`, etc.), then you could of course pin the inner-most array directly. It's not really clear from your code example what your scenario is, but given the code you posted, that's all you'd have really needed anyway. Well, actually…you didn't even need that, since you're just setting one element, but even assuming you're iterating over the elements of the array, it's not helpful to pin the arrays that hold the inner-most array. Those aren't the arrays you're looking for. :)

For example:

```cs
void SetBlock(int x, int y, int z, Block block)
{
   fixed (Block* b = &blocks[z][y][x])
   {
      b = block; // element at [x,y,z]
   }
}
```

or:

```cs
void SetBlock(int x, int y, int z, Block block)
{
   fixed (Block* b = blocks[z][y])
   {
      b = block + x; // element at [x,y,z]
   }
}
```